# Error in nested case query using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Trying to convert below query into `SQL`, query works fine on `MySQL`. Problem seems to be the `CASE WHEN` area field I get same error.

> show Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 44 Incorrect syntax near '='.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 47 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'AND'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 49 Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'ELSE'.

```
WHEN T.[StatusID] = 3
            THEN  
                CASE WHEN (((SELECT COUNT(TA1.[Approver_ID]) FROM [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_TicketApproval] TA1
                    INNER JOIN [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_ControlFlow_SubRoute] CFSR1 ON TA1.[SubRoute_ID] = CFSR1.[ID]
                    WHERE TA1.[Ticket_ID]= @iTkID AND TA1.Active=1  AND CFSR1.Active=1  AND CFSR1.[Sequence] =(SELECT CFSR2.[Sequence] FROM [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_Ticket] T2  INNER JOIN [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_ControlFlow_SubRoute] CFSR2 ON T2.[SubRouteID] = CFSR2.[ID]
                    WHERE T2.[ID] = @iTkID))<(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CFSR1.[ID])FROM [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_Ticket]  AS T1     INNER JOIN [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_ControlFlow_Route]  AS CFR1  ON T1.[FormID] = CFR1.[FormID] INNER JOIN [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_ControlFlow_SubRoute]  AS CFSR1  ON CFR1.[ID] = CFSR1.[RouteID]
                    WHERE CFR1.[Active] = 1 AND CFSR1.[Active] = 1 AND T1.[ID] = @iTkID AND CFSR1.[Category] = 1 AND  CFSR1.[Sequence] = ( SELECT CFSR2.[Sequence] FROM [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_Ticket]  AS T2 INNER JOIN [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_ControlFlow_SubRoute]  AS CFSR2 ON T2.[SubRouteID] = CFSR2.[ID]
                    WHERE T2.[ID] = @iTkID))))

                THEN
                    CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_TicketApproval] WHERE [Ticket_ID]=@iTkID And [Active]=1) = 0) 
                        THEN 
            --ERROR SHOW HERE =>    ((T.[AuditUser_ID] = '444' OR T.[AuditUser_ID] IS NULL) AND (nx.actor = 2 OR appSameSeq.NTLogin=in_NTLogin)
                            AND nx.actor=3 
                            AND srSameSeq.subRouteID NOT IN (SELECT subRouteID FROM [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_TicketApproval] WHERE [Ticket_ID]=@iTkID AND Active=1 )
                            AND appSameSeq.NTLogin=in_NTLogin 
                            AND nx.actor=3 AND srSameSeq.subRouteID NOT IN (SELECT subRouteID FROM [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_TicketApproval] WHERE [Ticket_ID] = @iTkID AND Active = 1)
                        ELSE 0
                    END
```

Comment: [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) definition for MSSQL. As the error says, your syntax is incorrect

Comment: yes, may i know is why the error show?
what syntax that i'm leaved.

Comment: @user3785636  Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'll toss my hat in the ring.

There may be more than one thing wrong with that SQL statement.  What I'll point out is this:

```
 CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [QESTORM].[dbo].  [CR_TicketApproval] WHERE [Ticket_ID]=@iTkID And [Active]=1) = 0) 
     THEN 
        --ERROR SHOW HERE =>    ((T.[AuditUser_ID] = '444' OR T.[AuditUser_ID] IS NULL) AND (nx.actor = 2 OR appSameSeq.NTLogin=in_NTLogin)
                        AND nx.actor=3 
                        AND srSameSeq.subRouteID NOT IN (SELECT subRouteID FROM [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_TicketApproval] WHERE [Ticket_ID]=@iTkID AND Active=1 )
                        AND appSameSeq.NTLogin=in_NTLogin 
                        AND nx.actor=3 AND srSameSeq.subRouteID NOT IN (SELECT subRouteID FROM [QESTORM].[dbo].[CR_TicketApproval] WHERE [Ticket_ID] = @iTkID AND Active = 1)
                    ELSE 0
                END
```

Are you trying to evaluate a conditional expression, and return the result as a 1 or 0, as if it were a Boolean expression in a programming language?

That doesn't work in TSQL.  This kind of expression evaluation:

```
SET  @value = (1 > 0)
```

... will produce an error.  You can't evaluate a conditional expression:  you can only use it in a test, like in a `WHERE`, `HAVING`, or `WHEN` clause.

So, if that's what you're doing, you might do better to wrap your conditional evaluation in yet another `CASE` statement, like this:

```
THEN
    CASE WHEN  {complex conditional statement}
         THEN  1
         ELSE  0
    END
ELSE 
    0
END
```

One other thing:  this is an *extremely* complex query statement!  I haven't analyzed it enough to see whether it could be simplified, but I'd suggest that you do so, with an eye toward using Common Table Expressions in place of some of your subqueries.  This can make the query a lot easier to understand (and debug).

Answer (score 0):

We are missing the complete query but it looks like you are opening too many parentheses.

If you look at the line where your error is shown:

```
((T.[AuditUser_ID] = '444' OR T.[AuditUser_ID] IS NULL) AND (nx.actor = 2 OR appSameSeq.NTLogin=in_NTLogin)
```

You are opening 2 parentheses but only close one.

That is why you get the error near `else` because you need to close that second parentheses before you can have an `else`

So you would need either

```
((T.[AuditUser_ID] = '444' OR T.[AuditUser_ID] IS NULL) AND (nx.actor = 2 OR appSameSeq.NTLogin=in_NTLogin))
```

or

```
(T.[AuditUser_ID] = '444' OR T.[AuditUser_ID] IS NULL) AND (nx.actor = 2 OR appSameSeq.NTLogin=in_NTLogin)
```

on that line

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a 'return value' for your case statement on that specific line.

When you flatten your CASE WHEN statement you have something like this:

```
CASE WHEN <something> THEN
  CASE WHEN <something else> THEN
    CASE WHEN <something else again> THEN
      -- THEN WHAT ?
    ELSE 
      0
    END
  END
END
```

Instead of putting a value on the --THEN WHAT spot, you put another conditional statement. You have to select a value here.